# How to play SoundPlayer with music from resources Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm want play music in Background the app visual basic, but i have button play to enter the game. I'm enter the music when mouse hover to button play and the background music stopped. I use the SoundPlayer to Mutiple the music

And how to call from resources in the string

```
Dim musicbackground As String = "My.Resources.backgroundlagu" '
Dim backmusic As New Media.SoundPlayer(musicbackground)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    backmusic.Play()
End Sub
```

Comment: The resource is a sound file? Then don't use a String, just use: `New Media.SoundPlayer(My.Resources.backgroundlagu)`

Comment: Assuming you have a .wav resource file, try with `My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.[ResourceName], AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)`

Comment: If I Use My.Computer.Audio.Play i can't use multiple sound in form1

Comment: @ChaseRocker i done use but music in the background not playing

Comment: Then define the Player (Class Scope): `Public backmusic As Media.SoundPlayer`. In Form.Load() (or Button.Click(), whatever),         `backmusic = New Media.SoundPlayer(My.Resources.filename)`
`backmusic.PlayLooping()`